# Naming a set of method,field,local var, and function

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, naming-conventions

In writing a compiler grammar, I'm trying to come up with a name/label for a set of elements that include pretty much everything with an ident in it: method, field, local var and function

I thought "members" first, but vars and functions aren't class members.  Any ideas?

EDIT:  This is higher up than an identifier.  Here's how it's used:

```
memberReference
 :
 IDENT
 | functionCall
 ;
// Then elsewhere
memberReference ('.' memberReference)*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just leaving it as "memberReference" even though I believe it's not precise.

Answer (score 1):

The common term for this is ID (identifier). ANTLR uses that token name a lot. For example, from [Software Development - Glossary](http://www.cs.ucc.ie/~dgb/courses/swd/glossary.html):

> **identifier** The name of something in a program. E.g. in Java, the name
>   of a variable, method, class,
>   interface or package.

Comment: I'm looking for something a little higher up from identifier.  See my edit above, but maybe there just isn't a term for it.